# Create Single Queue trigger azure function for multiple azure storage queues or single service bus trigger function for multiple topics

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, message-queue, azureservicebus

I have 5 different queues and I want to create an Azure function which should listen to all those queues but I have read that "QueueTrigger" attribute can listen to single queue only. Is there any way that I can create only 1 azure function and that will listen to messages coming in multiple queues?

If it is not possible with queues then will this be possible with topics?

My requirement is to create a single azure function and whenever a message comes in any queue, that function should trigger and listen to that message. Message can come in queue1, queue2, queue3, queue4 or queue5 but azure function is only 1 for all those queues.

```
 [FunctionName("RequestQueueWritebackFunction")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%RequestWritebackQueueName%", Connection =   "WritebackConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

By design, a Service Bus triggered function can only be triggered by a single entity (queue or subscription). While you cannot have a single function triggered by multiple queues, you can achieve what you need by changing your namespace topology. And what I mean by that is changing how your queues are working.

With Azure Service Bus, there's a feature called [Auto-Forwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding). Rather than storing the messages in the entity, the entity can forward the messages to another entity. In your case, you could consolidate messages from the various queues into a single queue and configure the Function to process messages from that queue. This is also known as fanning-in.

[image: fanning in]

There are pros and cons to this method. The pros probably outweigh the cons. For example, you can add and remove queues without modifying your function. But you'll need to be able to distinguish between the messages coming from the different queues. That should be done by using a custom header to indicate what the message is about rather than what entity it's coming from.

Also, there are other [messaging patterns](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/auto-forwarding-a-hidden-gem-of-service-bus) you can implement with Auto-Forwarding, but it goes beyond the scope of your question.